# Why do I get a constructor exception on JavaFX?

Tags: javafx

Based on [some online reference](https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2019/11/tutorial-reactive-spring-boot-a-javafx-spring-boot-application/), I try to bring up a JavaFX applicaion with the simple following code.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class DesktopApplication { 

              public static void main(String[] args) {
                            Application.launch(ChartApplication.class, args);
              }
}

public class ChartApplication extends Application {

            @Override
                public void start(Stage stage) { 

                }
}
```

I can't start up the app due to an error

```
me@USAUS desktop % java -jar target/desktop-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
Aug 18, 2022 4:10:10 PM com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl startup
WARNING: Unsupported JavaFX configuration: classes were loaded from 'unnamed module @69ec05a2'
Aug 18, 2022 4:10:15 PM com.sun.glass.ui.mac.MacApplication ambda$waitForReactivation$6
WARNING: Timeout while waiting for app reactivation
Exception in Application constructor
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
            at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
            at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
            at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
            at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
            at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49)
            at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:108)
            at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58)
            at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:65)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to construct Application instance: class com.example.desktop.ChartApplication
            at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:891)
            at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:196)
            at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.example.desktop.ChartApplication.<init>()
            at java.base/java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3585)
            at java.base/java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:2271)
            at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$8(LauncherImpl.java:802)
            at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$12(PlatformImpl.java:484)
            at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:457)
            at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
            at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:456)
            at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
```

I don't get why the class can't get constructed.

I use Java 17 and try various version of OpenJfx (versions from 18.0.2, 19 EA and 20 EA), and Spring Boot (2.7.3, 3.0.0-M4) with the same exception.

Comment: That’s the entire `ChartApplication` class? You don’t have a constructor defined somewhere that you’ve omitted from the question?

Comment: Are both public classes in the same file? More [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2366310/230513).

Comment: @trashgod That wouldn’t compile, would it?

Comment: @James_D: It should be a [_a compile-time error_](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.1); I'm guessing that the class might be a remnant.

Comment: I have tried to have those two classes in two different files as well as the ChartApplication class in the same file as DesktopApplication but not public. Remember, those two classes are taken straightly without any modification from the article. Also, a default constructor is a non-parameter constructor if it isn't any constructor defined.

Answer (score 0):

The cause is that JavaFX is removed from JDK after Java 11.